# Java JTable head not showing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, absolutelayout, jtableheader

Have a table I want to show in a panel when I click on a button. I am able to get the table to show, but I am not able to the header to show. Have also tried using the JscrollPane, but here nothing shows ups at all.

Main part of code:

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    JButton button;
    static JFrame frame;
    JTable tableA;
    JPanel TablePanel;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new GUI();

}

public GUI() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
    MainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
    MainPanel.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null,
            null, null, null));
    MainPanel.setBounds(0, 0, screen.width, screen.height - 60);
    MainPanel.setPreferredSize(screen);
    frame.getContentPane().add(MainPanel);
    MainPanel.setLayout(null);

    button = new JButton("Show Assignments");
    button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    button.setBounds(MainPanel.getWidth() / 2 - 65, 40, 130, 20);
    MainPanel.add(button);

    TablePanel = new JPanel();
    TablePanel.setBackground(new Color(245, 222, 179));
    TablePanel
            .setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
    TablePanel.setBounds(160, 85, MainPanel.getWidth() - 170,
            MainPanel.getHeight() - 95);
    MainPanel.add(TablePanel);
    TablePanel.setLayout(null);

    button.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());

    frame.setExtendedState(frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

What happens when you click button.

```
 class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String[] columnNames = { "AssignmentID", "Assignmenttype",
                    " AssignmentDesricption", "ClientID", "Status" };
            Object[][] data = {
                    {
                            "028079",
                            "Software Support",
                            "Danzafe is in need software support on their mail program.",
                            "25890", "Waiting" },
                    {
                            "028080",
                            "Software Installing",
                            "Danzafe is in need of installation of new software on thier server.",
                            "25890", "In Progress" },
                    { "028081", "Hardware Setup",
                            "Expert Beslag needs to get a new local server setup.",
                            "25891", "In Progress" },
                    {
                            "028082",
                            "Hardware Support",
                            "Expert Beslag have a computer that is making troubles with the wireless internet card",
                            "25891", "Waiting" },
                    {
                            "028083",
                            "Balacing Question",
                            "Blizzard needs help balacing out the class of World of Warcraft",
                            "00001", "Never Ends" } };

            tableA = new JTable(data, columnNames);
            tableA.setBounds(5, 35, TablePanel.getWidth() - 15,
                    TablePanel.getHeight() - 15);

            TablePanel.add(tableA.getTableHeader());
            tableA.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
            tableA.setVisible(true);
            TablePanel.add(tableA);
            TablePanel.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 3):

- have to put `JTable` into `JScrollPane`, then `JTableHeader` should be visible
- or to change `Layout Manager` for `JPanel` from default `FlowLayout` to the `BorderLayout`
- get `JTableHeader` from `JTable` and to put to the `NORTH` area
- proper way is usage of `JScrollPane` only
- don't to use `setBounds()`, use built_in `BorderLayout` for `JFrame` and put `JScrollPane` (only maybe there isn't reason to use `JPanel`, only in the case that you'll to planing to use `CardLayout`) to the `CENTER area`
- rest of `JComponent(s)` put to the separate `JPanel`, this `JPanel` put to the `NOTHR` or `SOUTH` area came from `JFrame`

Comment: Thanks for the help, sadly no matter what i do, it still wont work, so i would like to ask if i maybe could a example in code.

Comment: Pick an [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg).

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the table into scroll pane, and then add scroll pane into label. It should work this way, you may not have to do more than this.